# My iconpicker button submits my HTML form

Tags: php, html, icons, font-awesome

I have a problem with my iconpicker: In my form, i want the user to choose an icon. So i added an iconpicker button from FontAwsome. If i put it out of the form, it works. But when i put it into the form, what i just need to do, when i click on it, it submits the form.
I've tried to write "type='button'" but it not works.
Can someone help me and show what's wrong?
Thank you!

```
<body>
    <form method="post" id="form1" action="page_generator.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="free_links">
            <p >other</p>
            <div class="form row" id="free_a_cloner"style="display:none" >
                <div class="form-group col-1">
                    <button name="flnk_0[]" id="ipk" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-icon="fas fa-mouse-pointer" role="iconpicker" ></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <div class="form row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#ipk").iconpicker();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: look your `type="submit"` button is outside of the form tag and button without inside form tag with any type is by default submit button

Comment: Also when i put it into the form tags, there is the same problem

Comment: `<div class="form row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>`    move this row inside form tag  and give icon picker button type=button and check if it work please try

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work  either

Answer (score 0):

Specify that the buttun isn't of type submit by adding `type='button'`:

```
<button type='button' name="flnk_0[]" id="ipk" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-icon="fas fa-mouse-pointer" role="iconpicker" ></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But when i do this, it doesn't work. It means that the iconpicker doesn't open even if the form isn't submitted

Answer (score 0):

you forget to close a div and also try with type="button". sometime it may cause issues. Try the code below and better to create a pen for better understanding or provide head code as well thanks.

```
<body>
    <form method="post" id="form1" action="page_generator.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="free_links">
            <p >other</p>
            <div class="form row" id="free_a_cloner"style="display:none" >
                <div class="form-group col-1">
                    <button type="button" name="flnk_0[]" id="ipk" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-icon="fas fa-mouse-pointer" role="iconpicker" ></button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </form>
    <div class="form row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#ipk").iconpicker();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I corrected but it does not work. It means that when I write type = "button", the file is not submitted but the array of icons to be selected does not open.

Comment: can you help send me whole code with head section as well? thanks

Comment: yes. but how can i do this? the code is very long

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" and check source code on browser because it could be changed by javascript after page rendered and check if there is $("button").onClick.submit like javascript code.
be sure there is only 1 type property i mean not like that:

```
<button type="button" type="submit">
```

Comment: In my browser source code, i can see this: <i class="fas fa-mouse-pointer"></i><input type="hidden" name="flnk_0[]" value="fas fa-mouse-pointer"><span class="caret"></span>

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code!!

```
<button type="button" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But when i do this, it doesn't work. It means that the iconpicker doesn't open even if the form isn't submitted